# On click is laggy after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

My sidebar is laggy after ajax call.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $.post("<?php echo $baseurl;?>/api-cart-top.php",{ 
        unique: "<?php echo $unique;?>"
      },
      function(data) {
        $('#cartoon').html(data);
      });
      $('.rnd').on('click','#openside',function(){
          $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
      });
      $('.rnd').on('click','#closeside',function(){
          $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
      });
});
```

With ajax im giving unique code for cart items.

But after ajax call it is laggy. How I can get it smooth again.

I think it is laggy because ID #sidebar and #closeside,#openside..

Class .rnd is random div outside ajax call.

HTML:

```
<div class="total-cart total-cart-2 f-left rnd">
    <div id="cartoon" class="mini-cart">
        <?php include("api-cart-top.php"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

api-cart-top.php there it is getting unique code by ajax call #cartoon and inside php file is #openside and #closeside ID's.

HTML code inside api-cart-top.php:

```
<div class="total-cart-in">
    <div class="cart-toggler">
        <a href="#" id="openside" class="active">
            <span class="cart-quantity">1</span><br>
            <span class="cart-icon">
                <i class="zmdi zmdi-shopping-cart-plus"></i>
            </span>
        </a>                            
    </div>
    <nav id="sidebar" class="active">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <div style="display: flex;">
                <h3><i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle-o" id="closeside"></i></h3>
                <h3 style="padding-left: 25px;">Cart</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

First time I had jquery code just like this:

```
$('#openside').on('click',function(){/* code inside */}
```

This works only without ajax call..

Comment: Is `.rdn` a child of `#cartoon`? That could be unresponsive after an ajax request... Laggy... mmm... Can you describe it?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Edited code. Trying to open sidemenu (Cart) but it comes laggy if I remove #cartoon then it is all okay. So I expect it is ajax call what causes lagg.

Comment: While I don't get the laggy issue. It should be about click not working.

Comment: What is `.rnd`?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette `<div class="total-cart total-cart-2 f-left rnd">` there is class rnd.. It must be issue with ajax..

Answer (score 0):

subtile thing here...

`.rnd` includes `.#cartoon`, which includes `#openside`/`#closeside`.

**Now** `#cartoon` gets refreshed couple ms after the handlers are defined.

You secure your handlers "event responsible" static elements, using delegation...
But not the "dynamic slave" ones.

Try:

```
$('.rnd').on('click','#openside',function(){
  $(document).find('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
});
```

And same for `#closeside` *(which I hope are unique for a given time in the document.)*

Comment: Still laggy. Everytime refresh and click #openside it laggs alot.

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: Nothing inside console.

Comment: mm.. I don't know what a click on `#openside` does. But the click event occurs. From what you posted, there is no problem.